# Can i let make delete intermediate files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I somehow struggle to understand the *intermediate files* concept of `make.`

Consider this example of a make process:

Input files:

- `myProgram.code`
- `myGraphic.picture`

Build steps:

1. Cut off the borders of `myGraphic.picture`
2. Convert the cut graphic to a special format
3. Compile the code, including the converted graphic.

This is the concept:
[image: Concept drawing]

In a Makefile, this would look like this:

```
all: myProgram.exe

myProgram.exe: myProgram.code myGraphic.picture.cut.converted
    compiler -code myProgram.code -graphic myGraphic.picture.cut.converted

myGraphic.picture.cut.converted: myGraphic.picture.cut
    converter -in myGraphic.picture.cut -out myGraphic.picture.cut.converted

myGraphic.picture.cut: myGraphic.picture
    cutter -in myGraphic.picture -out myGraphic.picture.cut
```

As far as I understand, after running `make`, I will have the compiled program, **as well as the intermediate files `.cut.converted` and `.cut`**.

Is there a way to delete those files automatically? And if so, is make intelligent enough to not to recreate all of them when the original picture is unchanged?

Comment: To answer your second question first, yes, that's what intermediate files are: files that can be removed and GNU make will not recreate them if the don't need to be recreated.  You can read all about this here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html

Comment: @MadScientist _can_ be removed, or _will_ be removed? I would like it to get cleaned up by itself if possible

Comment: IIRC, the way it works is if the file was created by (this instance of) make, and it's intermediate, then make will remove it.  If the file already existed then make won't remove it.  You can easily try it for yourself however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target is specifically named in the Makefile, and not a dependency of the magic target `.INTERMEDIATE`, then it will be kept.

So add an `.INTERMEDIATE:` line, and/or rephrase your conversions to be pattern rules:

```
%.cut.converted: %.cut
    converter -in $< -out $@

%.picture.cut: %.picture
    cutter -in $< -out $@
```

This has a bonus of being easier to read, too.

You might be able to eliminate the need for at least some of the temporary files if the tools can be used as filters in a pipeline, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing easier. Just add [this target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets):

```
.INTERMEDIATE: myGraphic.picture.cut myGraphic.picture.cut.converted
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can delete files if you don't need them. For example:

```
results.txt : testzipf.py isles.dat abyss.dat last.dat
    python $^ *.dat > $@
    rm -f *.dat


.PONY : dats
dats : isles.dat abyss.dat last.dat

%.dat : books/%.txt countwords.py
    python countwords.py $< $@
```

This file create a results.txt from dats and finally delete the dat files `rm -f *.dat`

If you run `make` command again it will create the intermediate files again and delete them after utilising them to produce a target.

Your make script will look like

```
all: myProgram.exe
   rm -f *.cut
myProgram.exe: myProgram.code myGraphic.picture.cut.converted
   compiler -code myProgram.code -graphic        myGraphic.picture.cut.converted

myGraphic.picture.cut.converted: myGraphic.picture.cut
   converter -in myGraphic.picture.cut -out myGraphic.picture.cut.converted

myGraphic.picture.cut: myGraphic.picture
   cutter -in myGraphic.picture -out myGraphic.picture.cut
```